# How to configure rspec to load vue component for feature testing along with rails view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, rspec

I have used vue component along with rails view for particular feature. While writing test using rspec, the normal view is loading but the vue component is not loaded. Is there a way to load vue component along with rails view on spec? So that I could use rspec syntax for it, like:

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("//p", text: "This is loaded from vue component")
```

Comment: did you set the option `js: true` to your test?

Comment: Yes. I have added that but still it is not working.